# react component render method being called twice for no reason

Tags: reactjs, html-rendering

```
import './App.css';
import SolarSystem from './components/solarSystem/solarSystem';

class  App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("mounting");
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log("updating");
  }
  //const [SSVisibility, setSSVisibility] = useState(true);
  render(){ 
    console.log("rendering app");
    return (
    <div className="App">ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    {/*   <SolarSystem isShowing={"yolo"} toggle={"polo"}></SolarSystem> */}
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

With this simple code, my render method is being called twice. And i cant understand why[image]

Comment: My guess is that app is wrapped in a [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of strict mode, code below doesn't demonstrate it because SO will build it with production set true (I think).

```js
class Strict extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('mounting strict');
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('updating');
  }
  //const [SSVisibility, setSSVisibility] = useState(true);
  render() {
    console.log('rendering strict');
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/*   <SolarSystem isShowing={"yolo"} toggle={"polo"}></SolarSystem> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class NonStrict extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('mounting non strict');
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('updating');
  }
  //const [SSVisibility, setSSVisibility] = useState(true);
  render() {
    console.log('rendering Non strict');
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/*   <SolarSystem isShowing={"yolo"} toggle={"polo"}></SolarSystem> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Strict />
      </React.StrictMode>
      <NonStrict />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: 'though it may forever be obscure to me, i cannot but be aware of its power' - Captain Nathen Algren
I mean okay its because of strict mode but why though

Comment: @noob7 React needs to render multiple times to [detect possible problems](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). Strict mode  will not do this when build for production (that is why the snippet doesn't sow multiple logs)