# React empty useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Even though I'm working with React for some time, I can't figure this out. Why is the empty UseEffect causing component to re-render? The thing is I get two console.logs. Tnx!

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {

  }, [])

  console.log('render')

  return (
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Probably [strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899412/1641941) the effect does not cause App to re render.

Comment: In my case it was showing only once.

Comment: After @HMR mentioned strict mode I did some googling and found out that that my <App/> component was wrapped in <React.StrictMode>. After removing that, I only get one render. This link was also helpful https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Answer (score -1):

Empty `useEffect` subscribed to all the component's props.

```js
useEffect(() => console.log('rerendered due to new props'));
```

Any `useEffect` works at least once after first component's render. So you can use it like `componentDidMount`.

If you want to use it like `componentDidMount` only, you have to pass an empty array as the second param.

```js
useEffect(() => console.log('after first render'), []);
```

Subscribe to a specific prop:

```js
useEffect(() => console.log(' after first render or message updated', props.message), [props.message]);
```

Comment: This is not the reason that the COMPONENT re-renders.